# Control: what is the proper justification that you can't just make the output equal to the input if the system produces unstable output

Tags: control, control-system, math, theory, stability

Suppose we have a signal, it goes into the plant and generates an unstable response, a common question then arise at that point is why can't we just set our output to a "hard-coded" input. Think of this as an "if-else", if our signal coming in is this, then we bypass our plant and set input to be desired output.

Meaning, if we want to see a ramp coming out of our system but it gives us something that blows up, why can't we just create a ramp, set it equal to our output, bypassing the plant all together and viola, we are back in business.

What is the appropriate response to answer this question?

Comment: The plant is what you are trying to control, if you "bypass" it then you are not achieving control anymore.

Comment: How exactly can you hardcode,say, a speed of a motor?

Comment: Consider a cruise control on a car.  You measure speed, compare to desired speed, compensate, output an effective throttle position.  Now suppose your compensation makes the speed of the car unstable.  How do you propose to bypass the plant in that case?  A human can take over or you could revert to an open loop throttle position targeted at say 65MPH, but it's no longer a speed control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, its called [open loop control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-loop_controller) however that your system cannot compensate if there is any disturbances in the system or correct errors. Not to mention that most likely it would take a lot of trial and error to get the desired behavior coded into plant input

Answer (score 0):

If the system/plant is inherently stable, then letting it go on its own is certainly possible. You just turn everything off... But then you also let go of the control of the system and it will do whatever it wants. That might not be okay, for instance if your system/plant is something that takes a long time to restart.

Now, if the system is unstable (like a jet-engine fighter aircraft), then letting go would be an absolute disaster...